# Make line of text into json format

Tags: javascript, regex, json

I have a lot of company names that are all text, but I want to format them like this:

```
{
  "permalink": "3dplusme",
  "latitude": "",
  "longitude": ""
},
{
  "permalink": "3point5-com",
  "latitude": "",
  "longitude": ""
}
```

I have like 300 companies that are just text like this:

```
3dplusme
3point5-com
accessdata
acticut-international
adaptive-computing
airvend
...etc
```

I am looking for some regular expression that will do that for me. I'm trying to figure it out, but any help would be great! Thank you!

PS: The comma after the bracket may mess up the last company name but it wont matter because I can just manually fix it. I basically just want some help doing this so I dont have to manually do that. Thank you! :)

edit: Thank you all for your help!! You all helped me. Thanks

Comment: is each line supposed to be the `permalink` property?

Comment: This is a text file with all these names?

Comment: Yes. Its a text file with all these names and they are each on an individual line. and yes @PatrickEvans Sorry I meant to clarify that the latitude and longitutde were blank and the permalink is the only thing that needs to be filled in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use a regular expression you could use this: `var re =/([\s\S]*?)\n/gm;`

```
var myJson=[];
var str=$.trim($('#text').text());
var re =/([\s\S]*?)\n/gm;
var match;
while (match = re.exec(str)) {
    myJson.push({permalink:match[1],latitude:"",longitude:""});
}
```

Here is the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqdv6qqk/2/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a very simple regex like this:

```
(.*)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/iP8wS1/1)**

Check the substitution section

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If each line is supposed to be the permalink property you can split the string on the new line character and create a array. And then use the [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to create a new array of your data

```
var lines = variableHoldingText.split("\n");
var data = lines.map(function(item){
   return {permalink:item,latitude:"",longitude:""};
});

console.log(data);
//use JSON.stringify to get a json string
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r0e62bez/)

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is not a *regular expression* per se, but a *substitution* that uses a regular expression.

In Vim,

```
:%s/.*/{\r\t"permalink": "&",\r\t"latitude": "",\r\t"longitude": ""\r},/
```

I don't do JavaScript, but this is what I came up with.  Get your file into a string then:

```
var mystring = "a\nb\nc\n"
console.log(mystring.replace(/(.*)\n/mg , "{\n\t\"permalink\": \"$1\",\n\t\"latitude\": \"\",\n\t\"longitude\": \"\"\n}\n"));
```

Alternatively, you could iterate over the file line by line and just print your JSON string with the company name substituted in as a variable.